# Changing the range scale of values of arbitrary numeric types

Tags: c++, templates, range

I have a need to convert a collection of numbers from one range to another, while keeping the relative distribution of the values.

For example, a vector containing randomly-generated floats could be scaled to fit into possible unsigned char values (0..255).  Ignoring the type conversion, this would mean that whatever input was provided (e.g. -1.0 to 1.0) , all numbers would be scaled to 0.0 to 255.0 (or thereabouts).

I have created a template class to perform this conversion, which can be applied to a collection using `std::transform`:

```cpp
template <class TYPE>
class scale_value {
    const TYPE fmin, tmin, ratio;
public:
    TYPE operator()(const TYPE& v) {
        TYPE vv(v);
        vv += (TYPE(0) - fmin); // offset according to input minimum
        vv *= ratio;            // apply the scaling factor
        vv -= (TYPE(0) - tmin); // offset according to output minimum
        return vv;
    }
    // constructor takes input min,max and output min,max
    scale_value(const TYPE& pfmin, const TYPE& pfmax, const TYPE& ptmin, const TYPE& ptmax)
        : fmin(pfmin), tmin(ptmin), ratio((ptmax-tmin)/(pfmax-fmin)) { }
    // some code removed for brevity
};
```

However, the above code only works correctly for real numbers (`float`, `double`, ...). Integers work when scaling *up*, but even then only by *whole ratios*:

```cpp
float scale_test_float[] = {0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0};
int scale_test_int[] = {0, 5, 10, 15, 20};

// create up-scalers
scale_value<float> scale_up_float(0.0, 2.0, 100.0, 200.0);
scale_value<int> scale_up_int(0, 20, 100, 200);

// create down-scalers
scale_value<float> scale_down_float(100.0, 200.0, 0.0, 2.0);
scale_value<int> scale_down_int(100, 200, 0, 20);

std::transform(scale_test_float, scale_test_float+5, scale_test_float, scale_up_float);
// scale_test_float -> 100.0, 125.0, 150.0, 175.0, 200.0
std::transform(scale_test_int, scale_test_int+5, scale_test_int, scale_up_int);
// scale_test_int -> 100, 125, 150, 175, 200

std::transform(scale_test_float, scale_test_float+5, scale_test_float, scale_down_float);
// scale_test_float -> 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0
std::transform(scale_test_int, scale_test_int+5, scale_test_int, scale_down_int);
// scale_test_int -> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 : fails due to ratio being rounded to 0
```

My current solution to this issue is to store everything internal to `scale_value` as a `double`, and use type conversion as needed:

```cpp
TYPE operator()(const TYPE& v) {
    double vv(static_cast<double>(v));
    vv += (0.0 - fmin);                // offset according to input minimum
    vv *= ratio;                       // apply the scaling factor
    vv -= (0.0 - tmin);                // offset according to output minimum
    return static_cast<TYPE>(vv);
}
```

This works for most cases, albeit with some errors with integers, as the values are truncated rather than rounded.  For example scaling `{0,5,10,15,20}` from `0..20` to `20..35` and then back gives `{0,4,9,14,20}`.

So, my question is, is there a better method of doing this?  In the case of scaling a collection of `float`s, the type-conversions seem rather redundant, whereas when scaling `int`s there are errors introduced due to truncation.

As an aside, I was surprised not to spot something (at least, nothing obvious) in [boost](http://www.boost.org/) for this purpose. Maybe I missed it - the various maths libraries confuse me.

**Edit:** I realize I could specialize `operator()` for specific types, however this would mean a lot of code-duplication, which defeats one of the useful parts of templates. Unless there is a method to, say, specialize once for all non-float types (short, int, uint, ...).

Comment: What do you want your code to do if for example you try to scale the integer range `[1, 3]` to integer range `[1, 2]`? Should the source 2s be scaled to `1`, `2`, or a 50/50 split between the two result values?

Comment: I'm... undecided :) For my purposes, it doesn't really matter which happens - I think that adding in a 50/50 split would add a lot of complexity, requiring keeping track of previous values.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful piece of code. I always performed range scaling "by hand", always debugging a lot of stupid errors, this will save me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think that your `ratio` probably needs to be some floating point type and computed using floating-point division (possibly another mechanism would work too). Otherwise if you try for example to scale from `[0, 19]` to `[0, 20]` you'll wind up with an integral ratio of `1` and perform no scaling whatsoever!

Next, let's assume that things work fine for floating-point types. Now we'll just do all our math as `double`, but if the output type is integral we'd like to round to the closest output integer rather than truncating down. So we can use `is_integral` to force some rounding into place (note I don't have access to compile/test this right now):

```
TYPE operator()(const TYPE& v)
{
    double vv(static_cast<double>(v));
    vv -= fmin;                // offset according to input minimum
    vv *= ratio;               // apply the scaling factor
    vv += tmin;                // offset according to output minimum
    return static_cast<TYPE>(vv + (0.5 * is_integral<TYPE>::value));  // Round for integral types
}
```

Comment: +1: I like this approach (although is_integral is C++11.. is it also TR1?), as it means no code duplication. In my own answer I've tried to do something similar for C++03, but ended up specializing the whole class in order to remove the casts :)

Comment: Although I've ended up using [my own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15007297/218597) solution, I'm going to accept this, as it achieves my aim of not having to specialize for each individual type, and without C++11 we can use `boost::is_integral` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Following @John R. Strohm's suggestion, which would work for Integers, I have come up with the following, which seems to work with only a need to provide two specializations of the class (my concern was having to write a specialization for every type).  It does require writing a "trait" for each non-whole type, however.

First I create a "traits"-style class (note that in C++11 I think this is already provided in std::is_floating_point, but for now I'm stuck with vanilla C++):

```cpp
template <class NUMBER>
struct number_is_float { static const bool val = false; };

template<>
struct number_is_float<float> { static const bool val = true; };

template<>
struct number_is_float<double> { static const bool val = true; };

template<>
struct number_is_float<long double> { static const bool val = true; };
```

Using this traits-style class, we can provide a basic "whole number" implementation of the `scale_value` class:

```cpp
template <class TYPE, bool IS_FLOAT=number_is_float<TYPE>::val>
class scale_value
{
private:
    const double fmin, tmin, ratio;
public:
    TYPE operator()(const TYPE& v) {
        double vv(static_cast<double>(v));
        vv += (0.0 - fmin);
        vv *= ratio;
        vv += 0.5 * ((static_cast<double>(v) >= 0.0) ? 1.0 : -1.0);
        vv -= (0.0 - tmin);
        return static_cast<TYPE>(vv);
    }
    scale_value(const TYPE& pfmin, const TYPE& pfmax, const TYPE& ptmin, const TYPE& ptmax)
        : fmin(static_cast<double>(pfmin))
        , tmin(static_cast<double>(ptmin))
        , ratio((static_cast<double>(ptmax)-tmin)/(static_cast<double>(pfmax)-fmin))
    {
    }
};
```

...and a partial specialization for cases where the `TYPE` parameter has a "trait" that says it's a float of some kind:

```cpp
template <class TYPE>
class scale_value<TYPE, true>
{
private:
    const TYPE fmin, tmin, ratio;
public:
    TYPE operator()(const TYPE& v) {
        TYPE vv(v);
        vv += (TYPE(0.0) - fmin);
        vv *= ratio;
        vv -= (TYPE(0.0) - tmin);
        return vv;
    }
    scale_value(const TYPE& pfmin, const TYPE& pfmax, const TYPE& ptmin, const TYPE& ptmax)
        : fmin(pfmin), tmin(ptmin), ratio((ptmax-tmin)/(pfmax-fmin)) {}
};
```

The main differences between these classes is that with the whole-number implementation, the data in the classes is stored as a `double`, and there is built-in rounding as per John's answer.

If I decided I needed to implement a fixed-point class, then I guess I would need to add this as another trait.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding is your responsibility, not the computer's/compiler's.

In your operator(), you need to provide a "rounding bit" in the multiplication.

I'd try starting with something like:

```
TYPE operator()(const TYPE& v) {
    double vv(static_cast<double>(v));
    vv += (0.0 - fmin);                // offset according to input minimum
    vv *= ratio;                       // apply the scaling factor
    vv += SIGN(static_cast<double>(v))*0.5;
    vv -= (0.0 - tmin);                // offset according to output minimum
    return static_cast<TYPE>(vv);
}
```

You'll have to define a SIGN(x) function, if your compiler doesn't already provide one.

```
double SIGN(const double x) {
    return (x >= 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
}
```

Comment: A nice approach for various ints, but when TYPE is already a double or float, wouldn't it apply an unwanted offset of +/-0.5?

Comment: @icabod: You're right.  He'll have to use a template specialization to apply this version of operator() only to integer types.